# Inequality for Solution of 3-D Wave Equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

My Problem is about the following question found at [Bounding the solution of a wave equation in 3 dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/291877/1170005):
: Let $u: \mathbb{R}^3 \times (0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
be a solution of the Cauchy Problem:

$u_{tt} - \Delta u = 0 (x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \times (0,\infty); \\ 
u(x,0) = g; u_t(x,0) = h$
with $g,h \in C^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{R}^3)$ (g,h smooth with compact support)

Show that there exists a $C>0$ such that $|u(x,t)| <= C/t; (x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \times (0,\infty)$

So the answer given at the link above (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/742177/1170005) says that if you use Kirchoff's formula:

"Since $g,h,\nabla g$
are compactly supported, there exists $M>0$
such that $g,h, \nabla g=0$
on $S(x,t)$
for all $t⩾M$."
with $S(x,t)$ denoting the boundary of the ball with radius $t$ and center $x$.

My Question is:
I think $M$ in the answer given at the link above is dependend on $x$, because for different $x$ $M$ might vary, and thus the constant $C$ derived in the answer above is also dependend on $x$.
Is this correct or did i make a mistake?

Thank you for your help :)

Source: Evans, partial differential equations, problem 18 on page 8